# darken a button with an image in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm just looking for darken a button with an image in backgroud using swift 5. I just want darken the image, not the label in the button.
I tried lot of thing found on internet but does not work for me.

Comment: Just make a button and put an UIImage on top of it. Disable UIImage's user interaction.....

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Comment: Sry I begin, and how can I darken the UIimage after ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change opacity of the image then you can do like below,
but if you are asking to make the image more dark then you have to set dark image without any code in button directly.

```
    var img = UIImage()//set your image here
    img = img?.alpha(0.1)//set alpha to 

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal)
    btn.setTitle("hello", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 200, height: 20)//frame


extension UIImage {

    func alpha(_ value:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: value)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```